# Consolidating MySQL queries

Tags: php, mysql, sql, mysqli

I am wondering how 4 queries I use can be consolidated into one query. I was able to query for all days represented in my dataset and the number of clicks for each specific day. Ideally I would be able to get the number of installs (for each day), total cost (for each day) and notes (for each day) from that query as well.

I have thought about how to achieve this, but have not come up with any complete solutions as I am a novice with MySQL. Is there a good way to pull data from multiple tables?

```
$days = mysqli_query($link, "
    SELECT
      t1.date,
      t1.clicks
    FROM (SELECT
        date_format(date_sub(ic.click_utc, INTERVAL 7 HOUR), '%Y-%m-%d') as date,
        count(distinct ic.txid) as clicks
          FROM users_clicks ic
          GROUP BY date_format(date_sub(click_utc, INTERVAL 7 HOUR), '%Y-%m-%d')
          ORDER BY date DESC) t1
    WHERE date >= '2014-06-28'");
while ($day = mysqli_fetch_assoc($days)) {
    $date = $day['date'];
    $day_clicks = $day['clicks'];
    $day_installs = mysqli_fetch_row(mysqli_query($link, sprintf("SELECT count(txid) FROM (SELECT txid FROM users_installs WHERE date_format(date_sub(click_utc, INTERVAL 7 HOUR), '%%Y-%%m-%%d') = '%s' GROUP BY txid) table1", $day['date'])));
    $day_cost = mysqli_fetch_row(mysqli_query($link, sprintf("SELECT sum(earnings) FROM (SELECT max(cost) as earnings FROM users_clicks WHERE date_format(date_sub(click_utc, INTERVAL 7 HOUR), '%%Y-%%m-%%d') = '%s' GROUP BY txid) table1", $day['date'])));
    $note = mysqli_fetch_assoc(mysqli_query($link, sprintf("SELECT * FROM reporting_notes WHERE date_format(date_sub(timestamp, INTERVAL 7 HOUR), '%%Y-%%m-%%d') = '%s' LIMIT 1", $day['date'])));
}
```

**Here are the structures of the tables:**

Users_clicks:

```
   txid  |       click_utc        |  cost  
   12t3  |   2014-08-19 07:08:47  |  0.50
   27a5  |   2014-08-18 03:28:03  |  0.25
   48a5  |   2014-08-17 12:55:23  |  0.25
```

Users_installs:

```
   txid  |       click_utc 
   1o23  |   2014-08-19 07:08:47
   1ee3  |   2014-08-17 11:10:53
```

Reporting_notes:

```
      timestamp        |  note  
  2014-08-19 07:08:47  |  "hey"
  2014-08-17 03:02:41  |  "hey"
```

**desired output:** number of clicks, number of installs, sum cost and any notes for each individual day that is in the dataset

Comment: this is not going to help. Please post the structure of your tables and desired output then we will be able to help.

Comment: Nobody wants to see *that*. As raheel says, let's start from scratch

Comment: I've added in the structures for each table involved

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First off: MySQL is able to handle named time-zones, but you need to populate the information tables on time-zones first. See to documentation for [`CONVERT_TZ`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_convert-tz) as a starting point.

As your tables seem to be unrelated (i.e. there is no master-table containing all `txid`s, ...) you will probably be best off using sub-queries which are close to firing separate queries in the beginning.

#### Clicks and cost per day:

```
SELECT
  DATE(CONVERT_TZ(click_utc, '+00:00', '-07:00')) AS date,
  COUNT(*)                                        AS clicks,
  SUM(cost)                                       AS costs
FROM users_clicks
GROUP BY DATE(CONVERT_TZ(click_utc, '+00:00', '-07:00'));
```

Only counting each txid once

```
SELECT
  DATE(CONVERT_TZ(min_click_utc, '+00:00', '-07:00')) AS date,
  COUNT(*)                                            AS clicks,
  SUM(max_costs)                                      AS costs
FROM (SELECT
        txid,
        MIN(click_utc) AS min_click_utc,
        MAX(cost)      AS max_costs
      FROM users_clicks
      GROUP BY txid) distinct_txids
GROUP BY DATE(CONVERT_TZ(min_click_utc, '+00:00', '-07:00'))
```

#### Installs per day:

```
SELECT
  DATE(CONVERT_TZ(click_utc, '+00:00', '-07:00')) AS date,
  COUNT(*)                                        AS installs
FROM users_installs
GROUP BY DATE(CONVERT_TZ(click_utc, '+00:00', '-07:00'));
```

Only counting each txid once

```
SELECT
  DATE(CONVERT_TZ(min_click_utc, '+00:00', '-07:00')) AS date,
  COUNT(*)                                            AS installs
FROM (SELECT
        txid,
        MIN(click_utc) AS min_click_utc
      FROM users_installs
      GROUP BY txid) distinct_txids
GROUP BY DATE(CONVERT_TZ(min_click_utc, '+00:00', '-07:00'));
```

#### Notes per day

(note that [`GROUP_CONCAT`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/group-by-functions.html#function_group-concat) will by default only return 1024 characters. This can be changed by setting [group_concat_max_len](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/server-system-variables.html#sysvar_group_concat_max_len) to a higher value):

```
SELECT
  DATE(CONVERT_TZ(timestamp, '+00:00', '-07:00')) AS date,
  COUNT(*)                                        AS note_count,
  GROUP_CONCAT(note SEPARATOR ', ')               AS notes
FROM reporting_notes
GROUP BY DATE(CONVERT_TZ(timestamp, '+00:00', '-07:00'));
```

If you want to get everything at once you need to first get a common date-pool As MySQL only has `LEFT` or `RIGHT OUTER JOIN`s, but not `FULL OUTER JOIN`s:

```
SELECT DISTINCT
  date
FROM (
       SELECT
         DATE(CONVERT_TZ(click_utc, '+00:00', '-07:00')) AS date
       FROM users_clicks
       UNION SELECT
               DATE(CONVERT_TZ(click_utc, '+00:00', '-07:00')) AS date
             FROM users_installs
       UNION SELECT
               DATE(CONVERT_TZ(timestamp, '+00:00', '-07:00')) AS date
             FROM reporting_notes) dates;
```

and then you can combine it all into

#### one query

```
SELECT
  dates.date,
  clicks.clicks,
  clicks.costs,
  installs.installs,
  notes.note_count,
  notes.notes
FROM (SELECT DISTINCT
        date
      FROM (
             SELECT
               DATE(CONVERT_TZ(click_utc, '+00:00', '-07:00')) AS date
             FROM users_clicks
             UNION SELECT
                     DATE(CONVERT_TZ(click_utc, '+00:00', '-07:00')) AS date
                   FROM users_installs
             UNION SELECT
                     DATE(CONVERT_TZ(timestamp, '+00:00', '-07:00')) AS date
                   FROM reporting_notes) data) dates
  LEFT JOIN (SELECT
               DATE(CONVERT_TZ(click_utc, '+00:00', '-07:00')) AS date,
               COUNT(*)                                        AS clicks,
               SUM(cost)                                       AS costs
             FROM users_clicks
             GROUP BY DATE(CONVERT_TZ(click_utc, '+00:00', '-07:00'))) clicks ON clicks.date = dates.date
  LEFT JOIN (SELECT
               DATE(CONVERT_TZ(click_utc, '+00:00', '-07:00')) AS date,
               COUNT(*)                                        AS installs
             FROM users_installs
             GROUP BY DATE(CONVERT_TZ(click_utc, '+00:00', '-07:00'))) installs ON installs.date = dates.date
  LEFT JOIN (SELECT
               DATE(CONVERT_TZ(timestamp, '+00:00', '-07:00')) AS date,
               COUNT(*)                                        AS note_count,
               GROUP_CONCAT(note SEPARATOR ', ')               AS notes
             FROM reporting_notes
             GROUP BY DATE(CONVERT_TZ(timestamp, '+00:00', '-07:00'))) notes ON notes.date = dates.date;
```

The query gets easier if you know, that on each day where an install occurred, there also is a click as you can then use the click-query also as date-pool. In any case I would probably run a separate query to get the notes for each day to be able to act upon the text.

#### Count txids only once

And this query will ensure that each txid in users_installs and users_clicks is only counted once, on the earliest date it occurs. As there are two additional sub-sub-queries performance will be (at least) slightly worse. i would advice against this, if txids are already distinct. Performance can be increased, if you start filtering dates in the sub-queries.

```
SELECT
  dates.date,
  clicks.clicks,
  clicks.costs,
  installs.installs,
  notes.note_count,
  notes.notes
FROM (SELECT DISTINCT
        date
      FROM (
             SELECT
               DATE(CONVERT_TZ(click_utc, '+00:00', '-07:00')) AS date
             FROM users_clicks
             UNION SELECT
                     DATE(CONVERT_TZ(click_utc, '+00:00', '-07:00')) AS date
                   FROM users_installs
             UNION SELECT
                     DATE(CONVERT_TZ(timestamp, '+00:00', '-07:00')) AS date
                   FROM reporting_notes) data) dates
  LEFT JOIN (SELECT
               DATE(CONVERT_TZ(min_click_utc, '+00:00', '-07:00')) AS date,
               COUNT(*)                                            AS clicks,
               SUM(max_costs)                                      AS costs
             FROM (SELECT
                     txid,
                     MIN(click_utc) AS min_click_utc,
                     MAX(cost)      AS max_costs
                   FROM users_clicks
                   GROUP BY txid) distinct_txids
             GROUP BY DATE(CONVERT_TZ(min_click_utc, '+00:00', '-07:00'))) clicks ON clicks.date = dates.date
  LEFT JOIN (SELECT
               DATE(CONVERT_TZ(min_click_utc, '+00:00', '-07:00')) AS date,
               COUNT(*)                                            AS installs
             FROM (SELECT
                     txid,
                     MIN(click_utc) AS min_click_utc
                   FROM users_installs
                   GROUP BY txid) distinct_txids
             GROUP BY DATE(CONVERT_TZ(min_click_utc, '+00:00', '-07:00'))) installs ON installs.date = dates.date
  LEFT JOIN (SELECT
               DATE(CONVERT_TZ(timestamp, '+00:00', '-07:00')) AS date,
               COUNT(*)                                        AS note_count,
               GROUP_CONCAT(note SEPARATOR ', ')               AS notes
             FROM reporting_notes
             GROUP BY DATE(CONVERT_TZ(timestamp, '+00:00', '-07:00'))) notes ON notes.date = dates.date;
```

Comment: Thank you for putting this together. The one issue I have with it is that the number of clicks, number of installs and costs should based on distinct `txid` values. If there are multiple entries of clicks with the same `txid` and differing `cost` values, then the maximum `cost` should be selected.

Comment: @585connor can those entries be on different dates? How should that be handled?

Comment: the txids should be distinct across all days. If a click or install is recorded with the same txid on different dates, it should be counted once (preferably on the earliest date). Thank you!

Comment: @585connor been busy yesterday. Is that what you are looking for?

Comment: Thank you! I appreciate you taking your time to help me.

Answer (score 1):

Think this will require joining against sub queries.

One sub query to get the various dates used, then join that against a sub query to get the count and sub of clicks, and another to get the count of installs:-

```
SELECT sub0.aDate, click_count, click_cost, install_count, GROUP_CONCAT(reporting_notes.note)
FROM
(
    SELECT DATE(click_utc) AS aDate
    FROM users_clicks
    UNION
    SELECT DATE(click_utc)
    FROM users_installs
    UNION
    SELECT DATE(timestamp)
    FROM reporting_notes
) sub0
LEFT OUTER JOIN
(
    SELECT DATE(click_utc) AS aDate, COUNT(txid) AS click_count, SUM(cost) AS click_cost
    FROM users_clicks
    GROUP BY aDate
) sub1
ON sub0.aDate = sub1.aDate
LEFT OUTER JOIN
(
    SELECT DATE(click_utc) AS aDate, COUNT(txid) AS install_count
    FROM users_installs
    GROUP BY aDate
) sub2
ON sub0.aDate = sub2.aDate
LEFT OUTER JOIN reporting_notes
ON sub0.aDate = DATE(reporting_notes.timestamp)
GROUP BY sub0.aDate, click_count, click_cost, install_count
```

This could be done without the sub queries to do the counts if you only wanted unique notes and the sum wasn't required.